# Is there a way to search by sku with hyphen without extensions?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, search

I have some skus that have a very short string before the hyphen, like LC-100-PI, so the search brings up around 400 results that include "100" in them but the one I am looking for is not found until the third results page.

The top results I get are: TFC-1000S50, AC-100, TFC-1000MSC

Comment: Does your search in backend produces the same result? I yes then could you list those Sku's around 10 of them?

Comment: Stephanie, did you find a solution for this problem?

Comment: No, I did not. The only "solution" was to use Elastic Search but it created more problems and we had to remove it, but our site is pretty customized and that's what it was affecting, maybe you could try Elastic or SOLR.